# Inheritance, Generics and Casting in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

I have two classes which both `extends Example`.

```
public class ClassA extends Example {

    public ClassA() {
        super("a", "class");
    }
    ...
}

public class ClassB extends Example {

    public ClassB() {
        super("b", "class");
    }
    ...
}

public class Example () {

    public String get(String x, String y) {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

So thats all very well. So suppose we have another class called ExampleManager. With example manager I want to use a generic type and consequently return that generic type. e.g.

```
public class ExampleManager<T extends Example> {

    public T getExample() {
        return new T("example","example"); // So what exactly goes here?
    }
}
```

So where I am returning my generic type how do i get this to actually work correctly and cast `Example` as either `classA` or `classB`?

Many Thanks

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java

Comment: You're looking for *Reified Generics*. This is not supported in Java. C# supports it. In Java generics are only compiletime. Lookup the factory pattern, see the above link to duplicate question for the correct answers.

Comment: @BalusC: do you see how to apply factory pattern here? I just don't get how to implement `E create()` method in Factory (from Tom Hawtin - tackline answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java/75528#75528)

Comment: @Roman: either by reflection (`Class#newInstance()` or even grabbing the constructor) or just using the `new` keyword. The factory pattern is just intented to abstract this away (which is the intent of the OP).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a generic type to instantiate new object (i.e. you can't do `new T(params)`).

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a concrete instance of object (that is, you use *new*), you have know the actual implementing class, you can't use a generic type.

What are you actually trying to achieve? How do you decide whether you want to create ClassA or ClassB?

Try this:

```
public class ExampleManager {
    public ClassA createClassA() {
        return new ClassA("example","example");
    }

    public ClassB createClassB() {
        return new ClassB("example","example");
    }
}
```

or this:

```
public class ExampleManager {
    public Example createExample() {
        if(a == b) {
           return new ClassB("example","example"); 
        }
        return new ClassB("example","example"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can't use new to create a new instance of an unknown type. Without using reflection, you could make ExampleManager an abstract superclass of factories.

```
public abstract class ExampleManager<T extends Example> {
     public abstract T getExample(String x, String y);
}

public class ClassAManager extends ExampleManager<ClassA> {
     public ClassA getExample(String x, String y) {
          return new ClassA(x, y);
     }
}

public class ClassBManager extends ExampleManager<ClassB> {
     public ClassB getExample(String x, String y) {
          return new ClassB(x, y);
     }
}
```