# Is there a way to define a generic method that checks for null and then create the object?

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

I'd like to write a method that checks where the argument is null, and if it is, returns a new object of that type. it looks like:

```
public static <T> T checkNull(T obj) {
    if (null == obj) return someHowCreateTheObjectWithTypeT();
    else return obj;
}
```

After some struggling and digging, I still can't get a way to achieve this, is it atually possible in java?

I thought about reflection at first. But I just can't get a Class instance when the object is null, and you can't create a Class without the type T's name...

Update:

I thought about passing a Class as a parameter, but that's not the best solution, as the following answers shows :)

My currunt solution is to use a defaultValue parameter:

```
public static <T> T checkNull(T obj, T defaultValue) {
    if (null == obj) return defaultValue;
    return obj;
}
```

Which is faster and safer than a reflection solution, and is the same verbose;
But then I have to systematically specify a DEFAULT_VALUE for all types of interest, which is not an easy work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: What if `T` is an interface or abstract type? How would you know what constructor to call?

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a good replacement for a null check, but there's no good way to do this. As @MattBall said, what if its an interface or abstract class, which class do you instantiate? What if the class has multiple constructors? Null checks in java are meant to be handled on a case by case basis. It'd be really nice simplify a null check like that, but in practice, it doesn't really work out.

Comment: to thecoop: thanks. I've read that post, they are duplicate somehow, but my situation is a static generic method which does not involve type hierarchies, and it's about `null`.

Comment: to Matt Ball and shoebox639: thanks for mentioning safety problems with the reflection solution. It's partly why I didn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

Generic information is compile time only and not available at runtime. You'd have to pass the Class of the object in as a hint, and the class would have to have a public default constructor. e.g.

```
public static T checkNull(Object o, Class<T> c) {
  try {
    return (o == null) ? c.newInstance() : o;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't null be a bad return value, since the whole reason one would call such a method is to be sure that the returned value is not null.  Also, I suspect you can't just return o without a downcast.

Comment: Thanks locka and Ophidian. I've tried that and it seems not the best solution as Ophidian explained.

Comment: Either you return null or you propagate the exception or you are exceedingly careful what classes you call the method with and craft the code accordingly. The issue is that the newInstance() method will throw an exception if you try to construct an abstract class, interface or a class where the default constructor does not exist or is hidden.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.  For generics to work in this manner, it has to capture at compile-time the type that it will be called with.  However, `null` has no type so you won't be able to figure out T to instantiate it.

Now, you may be able to work around this also passing in the Class instance, but you will need some rather robust error handling using Reflection to ensure that type T is a concrete class and has a public parameterless constructor that you can invoke.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be done. You must add an additional parameter of `Class<T>`, and then use it to reflectively new. The type T does not survive the compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this can't be done. However, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides an equivalent to the default value you method you posted:

```
String foo = Objects.firstNonNull(someString, "default");
```

This differs slightly from your method in that `firstNonNull` will throw a `NullPointerException` if both arguments are `null`.

Another option would be to create a method that makes use of Guava's `Supplier<T>` interface or something similar:

```
public static T firstNonNull(T first, Supplier<? extends T> defaultSupplier) {
  return first != null ? first : Preconditions.checkNotNull(defaultSupplier.get());
}
```

You could then use a `Supplier` that creates and returns a new default instance when and only when the first argument is null.

Comment: Thanks, it looks better to throw a NPE for the second param. As for guava's Supplier, i don't quite get it yet. Is it just a 'lazy' solution, or does it have some other benefits? I'll have to look into it.

Comment: It's basically just a lazy solution. `Supplier` is just an interface with a method `T get()`. You can implement it however you want. In this case, you could implement it to return a new instance of an object of a particular type. Obviously, you'd need to do this implementation for any type of object you wanted to use with the method, but it'd be type-safe, lazy and not involve reflection... pretty much the best you can do until we have method references in Java 8.