# Create new instance of T in Java

Tags: c#, java, generics, design-patterns

in C#, we can define a generic `class A<T> where T : new()`. In this code, we can create an instance of `T` with `new T()`. How does this implement in Java? I read some article which says it's impossible.

The reason that I used have a singleton patten using generic in C# like:

```
public static class Singleton<T> where T : new()
{
    private static T instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = SingletonCreater.Instance;
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    static class SingletonCreater
    {
        internal static readonly T Instance = new T();
    }
}
```

And way to make this method more graceful?

Comment: by the way, you might be interested in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't do new T(), since you don't know if T has a no arg constructor, and because the type of T is not present at runtime due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

To create an instance of T, you need to have code like,

```
public <T> T create(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        //T must have a no arg constructor for this to work 
        return clazz.newInstance(); 
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

Comment: I see, so I cannot implement like the way I used in C#, right? We can keep this open and see if there is any other idea. :)

Comment: in c#, how do you know that T has a no arg constructor?

Comment: In the class definition, we have where T : new() which means this T accepts none-argument constructor :)

Comment: No-arg constructor is not an issue at all. Type erasure is.

Comment: In this part, MS' API is more powerful I think.

Comment: @road to yamburg, even without type erasure, you cant do new T(), since you can't ensure that T has a no arg constructor.

Comment: @sbridges - The compiler can, in theory, determine if T has a no arg constructor at compile time, since it knows what type it was instantiated with and if that type has such a constructor.

Comment: @RHSeeger - the compiler can't even in theory, unless the method is visible only to the one compilation unit.  If the bound is T extends List say, there is no fixed set of types that T can be, since the .class file may be used by code not compiled with the .java file.

Comment: @sbridges - And, if you had "new T()" and you tried to instantiate it with a List, it would be able to say "Nope, can't do that, List doesn't support such a constructor"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `new T()` is impossible as generic is a compile time feature in Java. During runtime the generic information is lost; therefore, you will not be able to do `new T()` since the JVM have no idea what `T` is during runtime.

You might be out of luck to use the exact syntax as you mentioned using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, in all, we cannot use it in JAVA. As Sbridges' way, in C#, we can implement like this:

```
static T Create(Type type)
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

or even easier:

```
static T Create()
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

Just let you know.