# Question about java generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am writing this query service that's suppose to work with couple predefined classes. However, it seems to me to be redundant that, when using this service class, I need to pass both the Type of the class and a class object it self. For example, to query "Contact" object, I'll need to provide both  and Contact.class, like the following:

```
lookupService = new MyLookupServiceImpl<Contact>(Contact.class);
```

In this case, is there a way to initialize Class without passing in "Contact.class"?
The service class look like the following:

```
public class MyLookupServiceImpl<T> {
private Class<T> cls;

public MyLookupServiceImpl(Class<T> clz){
    this.cls = clz;
}

public T queryObject(String sql) {
    try {
        QueryResult result = ConnectionFactory.getConnection().query(sql);
        if(result.getSize()>0){
            T obj=null;
            MyObject sObj = result.getRecords()[0];
            MyObjectBuilder<T> ob = new MyObjectBuilder<T>(cls);
            obj = ob.buildORMObject(sObj);
            return obj;
        }
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        logger.warn(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO. In java, because of [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there is no other way infer/get this info at runtime other that passing in the type info as a  `Class<?>` instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely necessary because it is not possible to create a new instance of an arbitrary class indicated by a type parameter; in other words, you cannot do:

```
T obj = new T();
```

because of the way Java generics are implemented (with type erasure).

Note that in your code, `cls` is passed to `MyObjectBuilder<T>` which is most likely an object that creates new instances of `T`. `MyObjectBuilder<T>` uses reflection to create a new instance of `T`, with a statement like this:

```
T obj = cls.newInstance();
```

See also: [Create new instance of T in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710546/create-new-instance-of-t-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Bala is correct (+1) unfortunately.  However, if you use a Dependency Injection framework like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) you could ask Guice to pass you a TypeLiteral which is the type you're interested in.  You could do something like this:

```
public class MyLookupServiceImpl<T> {
    private Class<T> cls;

    @Inject
    public MyLookupServiceImpl(TypeLiteral<T> type){
        this.cls = (Class<T>)type.getRawType();
    }
}
```

Then use the Guice Injector to pass you instances of MyLookupServiceImpl.  Just an idea! :)