# Can't construct generic type arguments, what to do instead?

Tags: java, list, generics, type-erasure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

I only found out that Java doesn't let you construct new instances of generic type arguments after trying to write this:

```
public static <C extends JSONSerializable> List<C> JSONtoList(JSONArray data) {
    List<C> list = new ArrayList<C>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
        list.add(new C(data.get(i)));
    }
    return list;
}
```

This doesn't compile, but I think its obvious what I'm trying to do. How can I do it?

Comment: can you include the error message?  I don't think Java let's you do constructors on generic objects.

Comment: @BrianNickel you are correct. This is an example of how I would do it if Java supported this.

Comment: The generics implementation is actually bigger things I miss from working with .Net (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx).  You would think with beans being such a common component in Java, they would make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GSON, this is actually quite easy:

```
public static <C extends JSONSerializable> List<C> jsonToList(JsonArray data, Class<C> type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<C> list = new ArrayList<C>();
    for (JsonElement e : data)
        list.add(gson.fromJson(e, type));
    return list;
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to use reflection or the `newInstance` method of `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is one option; another is to have your method take a second argument, a generified factory. For instance, guava defines a [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html):

```
public interface Function<F,T> {
    T apply(F input);
}

public static <C extends JSONSerializable> List<C> JSONtoList(
    JSONArray data,
    Function<Object,C> factory)
{
        List<C> list = new ArrayList<C>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            C instance = factory.apply(data.get(i)) // instead of new
            list.add(instance);
        }   
        return list;
}
```

(As I recall, `JSONArray.get(int)` returns `Object`, right? If not, replace the factory's `F` with whatever that method returns.)

The idea here is that the call site will know what `C` actually is, and it'll be able to define an implementation of `Function` which, given the JSON array element, returns back a new `C` instance. Most likely, you'll have this as a `private static final` anonymous class.