# Is it possible to instantiate a generic class by casting a "new Object()" as the generic class?

Tags: java, generics, object, casting, instantiation

So I am attempting to create a class which uses a generic which extends an abstract class.
Ex.

```
public abstract class Template<C extends Abstract>
```

However, I need to instantiate this 'C' within my class. I figured I might be able to do this:

```
C s = (C) ((C)new Object()).getClass().getConstructor(Known.class,AnotherKnown.class).newInstance(objectOfKnownType,objectOfAnotherKnownType);
```

So my question is basically whether this is possible. I feel like the

```
((C) new Object()).getClass()
```

might give me some problems.

What if i changed it to:

```
C a;
C s = (C) (a.getClass().getConstructor( ... ).newInstance( ... ));
```

Comment: Yes, it "might" give you some problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(C) new Object()
```

is not valid and may give you a `ClassCastException` later, since an `Object` is not a `C`.

[The way generics are implemented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) means `Template` will have no knowledge of the `C` it was instantiated with, you will have to create a method or constructor that takes a `Class` object.

```
public abstract class Template<C extends Abstract>
{
    private Class<C> classOfC;

    public Template( Class<C> clazz ) {
        classOfC = clazz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is due to the nature of the generics in Java Bytecode. In .NET you can access this information using reflection.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Class<C>`?

Comment: @Jeffrey: It could be, but again generics have no notion of the argument they are instantiated with...

Comment: That said, it's advisable to use a factory object instead, as reflection is pretty fragile.  (Many objects _deliberately_ don't expose constructors...)

Comment: @K-ballo Well, if it isn't `Class<C>`, your solution would no longer be type safe. You could pass `Object.class` into that constructor and the compiler wouldn't be any the wiser.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what do you mean factory object? would that piece of code be considered poor programming practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830865/instantiate-generic-type-in-java/10830904#10830904

Comment: "will give you a ClassCastException" No it won't, not there, if the erasure of `C` is `Object`, since, as you say, "Template will have no knowledge of the C it was instantiated with". It may (or may not) give you a ClassCastException later on depending on whether you return that value outside the scope of the erasure

Comment: @newacct: Great point you make, feel free to edit my answer to include that information.