# Generic array creation in java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)
>   [Java how to: Generic Array creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

I am trying to create a create a class of generic type. This is my class file.

```
public class TestClass<T> implements AbstractDataType<T>{

    T[] contents;

    public TestClass(int length) {
        this.contents = (T[])new Object[length];
    }
}
```

But the contents have just have the methods inherited from the `Object class`. How can I create an abstract array for contents ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as initializing `contents`, I think what you have is the best you can do.  If there way a way, `ArrayList` would probably do it (line 132: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html)

But when you say "the contents have just have the methods inherited from the Object class", I'm assuming you mean that you can only access methods like `toString` and `equals` when you are working with a T instance in your code, and I'm guessing this is the primary problem.  That's because you're not telling the compiler anything about what a `T` instance is.  If you want to access methods from a particular interface or type, you need to put a type constraint on `T`.

Here's an example:

```
interface Foo {
  int getSomething();
  void setSomethingElse(String somethingElse);
}

public class TestClass<T extends Foo> implements AbstractDataType<T> {
  T[] contents;

  public TestClass(int length) {
    this.contents = (T[])new Object[length];
  }

  public void doSomethingInteresting(int index, String str) {
    T obj = contents[index];
    System.out.println(obj.getSomething());
    obj.setSomethingElse(str);
  }
}
```

So now you can access methods other than those inherited from `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a generic array in Java.
As stated in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10), the mentioned rules state that "The rules above imply that the element type in an array creation expression cannot be a parameterized type, other than an unbounded wildcard."

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in any method that accesses contents, you need to cast them as type `T`. The main reasoning for this is that as an Object array, Java looks at the contents as Objects to fit them in. So while `contents` might be an array of `T`, it still is just an array of type `Object`.

Comment: -1 for incorrect information: `contents[0]` already is of type `T`, casting it to `T` won't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

How do you think `ArrayList.toArray` and `Arrays.copyOf` do it?

See [`Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29).

```
public TestClass(Class<T> type, int length) {
    this.contents = Array.newInstance(type, length);
}
```

Comment: @meriton updated my answer. PS `null` has the methods provided by *any* reference type.