# Create instance of a generic class

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

I got these classes

```
public abstract class Base {
    public String Id = "originalId";
}

public class InstanceOfBase extends Base {
    public void setString(String test) {
        this.Id = test;
    }
}

public class UseIt {
    public Test<InstanceOfBase> test = new Test<InstanceOfBase>();

    public void run() {
        InstanceOfBase instanceOfBase = test.createMe();
        System.out.println(instanceOfBase.Id);
    }
}

public abstract class Test<E extends Base> {
    public E createMe() {
        // How do I do this?
        return new E();
    }
}
```

The code above does not compile because it does not know how to create E. how can I achieve this?

When I invoke the run method, I expect it should print "originalId".

Comment: Note that one of the reasons why it is not possible without reflection is that if `InstanceOfBase` had a private constructor, for example, it would not be instantiable with `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot create classes from generic types in java. But you can do as Justin Rudd suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java) and write:

```
public E createMe(Class<E> clazz)
{
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

So you use the `class` archetype to create a new instance. Invoking it could be:

```
InstanceOfBase instanceOfBase = test.createMe(test.getClass)
```