# Java Generics Causing Class Cast Error

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

So I'm coding up a generic adjacency list and my code has no compile errors, but when I run my tests I get the same runtime error across the board:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Lds.Graph.Edge;
    at ds.TheAdjacencyMatrix.AdjacencyMatrix.<init>(AdjacencyMatrix.java:86)
    at ds.TheAdjacencyMatrix.AdjacencyMatrix.<init>(AdjacencyMatrix.java:63)
    at ds.TheAdjacencyMatrix.AdjacencyMatrix.<init>(AdjacencyMatrix.java:73)
    at ds.Graph.Test.TheAdjacencyMatrixTest.testAddVertex(TheAdjacencyMatrixTest.java:33)
```

The error is in the constructor on the line where I cast the 2d object array to E[][] type

The relevant code for the adjacency matrix is::

```
public class AdjacencyMatrix<T, E extends Edge> 
        implements AdjacencyMatrixInterface<T, E>, Graph<T, E> {

    //~Constants----------------------------------------------
    private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;

    //~Data Fields--------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Int matrix that holds edge weights in weighted graphs. 
     * A 1 in a directed graph indicates an edge, a 0 indicates no edge.
     */
    private E[][] matrix;

    /**
     * Array of elements contained in the graph.
     * Elements correspond to the same indices as they do in the adjacency matrix of edges.
     * 
     * i.e. matrix[4][5] is an edge from 4 to 5, 
     *  elements[4] is the element at 4, elements[5] is the element at 5
     */
    private T[] elements;

    /**
     * The maximum number of vertices in the adjacency matrix.
     */
    private int size;

    /**
     * The current number of vertices in the graph.
     */
    private int numVertices;

    /**
     * Indicates whether the graph is directed or not. True if directed, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean directed;

    //~Constructors--------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Initializes the adjacency matrix to a size of 10.
     * Which means there are 10 vertices in the graph.
     */
    public AdjacencyMatrix() {

        this(DEFAULT_SIZE);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the adjacency matrix to a size of 10. There will be 10 vertices in the graph.
     * 
     * @param directed true if the graph is to be a directed graph, false otherwise.
     */
    public AdjacencyMatrix(boolean directed) {

        this();
        this.directed = directed;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the adjacency matrix to a size of size.
     * There will be a maximum size of *size* vertices in the graph
     * 
     * @param size the size of the adjacency matrix.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AdjacencyMatrix(int size) {

        matrix = (E[][]) new Object[size][size];
        elements = (T[]) new Object[size];

        this.size = size;
        numVertices = 0;
        directed = false;
    }
```

And the Edge class is an abstract class whose code is here:

```
package ds.Graph;

/**
 * An abstract Edge class which has methods
 * getWeight()
 * and
 * setWeight(int weight).
 * Used for a Graph data structure to abstract
 * out the edges.
 * 
 *
 *
 */
public abstract class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {

    /**
     * Sets the weight of the edge to the passed in weight.
     * 
     * @param weight the weight of the edge.
     */
    public abstract void setWeight(int weight);

    /**
     * Gets the weight of the edge.
     * 
     * @return the edge weight.
     */
    public abstract int getWeight();
}
```

EDIT::

So this is the line of code that sets of the error at runtime. IntEdge is just an object inheriting from Edge that holds an integer.

```
AdjacencyMatrixInterface<String, IntEdge> matrix = new AdjacencyMatrix<String, IntEdge>(false);
```

Comment: The moral of the story: don't use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` without understanding why you need it.

Comment: Java Generics isn't causing this error. You are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple change that line to

```
matrix = (E[][]) new Edge[size][size];
```

`E` is erased to its upper bound inside the class. `E`'s upper bound is `Edge` in this case. So it will try to cast to `Edge[][]`.

Also, you have to make sure that `matrix` and `elements` is not exposed to the outside as `E[][]` and `T[]` respectively, since they are not really of those types. But as long as you only use them within the class, there is no problem.

Comment: The problem here is that E is an abstract class. I want to be able to define objects that inherit from Edge and then just be able to throw them into this. So I could either go the abstract class or interface route...but both give me the same error

Comment: And wait...so since Edge[][] is what the cast is replaced by...then wouldn't my issue actually be that I'm setting a reference of some type that inherits from Edge to refer to the casted object array?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Object[][] is not an instance of Edge[][]. You can't cast your objects like that.

```
new Object[][] {} instanceof Edge[][] // => false
```

Its the other way around Object[][] is in fact superclass of Edge[][]

```
new Edge[][] {} instanceof Object[][] // => true
```

Also, According to [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3)

> The direct superclass of an array type is Object. Every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and java.io.Serializable.

**Edit:**

Also, [as Rahul Bobhate pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643613/java-generics-causing-class-cast-error/16644169#16644169), its better to use [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) since it was designed to utilize generics. All [array-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation) workarounds are [are pretty ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

This is not right, you must be getting unchecked cast warning:

```
matrix = (E[][]) new Object[size][size];
        elements = (T[]) new Object[size];
```

You need to explicitly pass array instances since generic information is erased at runtime (which means at runtime code under execution would be `matrix = new Object[][]`)

You can have constructor like:

```
public class AdjacencyMatrix<T, E extends Edge> 
        implements AdjacencyMatrixInterface<T, E>, Graph<T, E> {
E[][] matrix;
T[] elements;
public AdjacencyMatrix(int size, E[][] matrix, T[] elements) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.elements = elements;
   }
}
```

Comment: ...or using Collections instead of arrays would help here also I think

Comment: You say "generic information is erased at runtime", and this is true, but the generic types are replaced by their upper bounds, so at runtime the code becomes `matrix = (Edge[][]) new Object[][]` which results in a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an array of `Object` to an `E`. Although it will compile, it will cause `ClassCastException` at runtime. You can cast only compatible reference types. Since an array of `E` and array of `Object` are not related in any way, JVM won't be able to cast the array of `Object` to array of `E`.

You can use List instead of array. You could define matrix as a `List` of `List` as follows:

```
private List<List<E>> matrix;
private List<T> elements;
```

You can then initialize `matrix` in the constructor easily:

```
public AdjacencyMatrix(int size) {

    matrix = new ArrayList<List<E>>(size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        t.add(new ArrayList<E>());
    }

    elements = new ArrayList<T>(size);

    this.size = size;
    numVertices = 0;
    directed = false;
}
```

You can then access the elements inside the list as follows:

```
E e = matrix.get(0).get(1);
```

This will fetch you the 2nd element in the 1st list.

Comment: "it will cause ClassCastException at runtime" Not necessarily. `E` will be erased to its upper bound inside the class. If its upper bound is `Object`, then no `ClassCastException` will happen on that statement.

Comment: ^Could you elaborate on that? How could I make the upper bound object?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because even though E is a subclass of Object, E[] is not a subclass of Object[]. Arrays have a flat class hierarchy and thus can't be cast into each other.

[Edit]

I was wrong (thx for the comment). Actually there is a type hierarchy for arrays (see http://etutorials.org/cert/java+certification/Chapter+6.+Object-oriented+Programming/6.5+Completing+the+Type+Hierarchy/ ). As correctly pointed out, you are thus trying to cast a supertype instance to a subtype, which won't work for any other Java Objects as well.

Comment: You have it backwards - `E[][]` *is* a subclass of `Object[][]`, but a plain `Object[][]` can't be cast to the erasure of `E[][]`, which is `Edge[][]`.