# Get class name for the generic class argument

Tags: java, generics

I want to find the class name of the argument sent to the generic class as follows.

`public abstract class RootClass<T extends Iface> {
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public T getIfaceBean() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(T.class);
    }
}`

But it looks like I can't do `T.class` (due to [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)?).

So, Is such an action possible with *Java Generics* ?

How can I achieve this type of functionality with Java Generics?

Comment: It's hacky, you're better off passing the Class type as an argument to the constructor or method.

Comment: Same thing as with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java You have to pass the class as an argument.

Comment: You can obtain this via reflection if you have a subclass (as you must have) and concrete type. Here is an example http://ideone.com/9ZFujO

Comment: @PeterLawrey Using reflection for this purpose seems complex. I have had figure out a simple solution by requiring concrete-classes to implement `getIfaceClass()` which just do `return SubIface.class`.

Comment: That is fine if you don't have to do it very often.  Doing what you believe is simplest is the best approach.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Can you please help me write code in abstract class using reflection instead of implementing `getIfaceClass()` in concrete class?

Comment: You can copy the code from my example, see the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of Type Erasure, you can't say `T.class` because `T` doesn't exist at runtime.

The best you can do is to take a parameter of type `Class<T>` to get the `Class` object:

```
public T getIfaceBean(Class<T> clazz) {
```