# Create instance of generic type in Java within the generic class

Tags: java, class, generics, instantiation, generic-programming

According to the question, [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

At the time of writing ,the best answer is found to be...

```
private static class SomeContainer<E> { 
    E createContents(Class<E> clazz) { 
       return clazz.newInstance(); 
    }
 }
```

But the answer works only for this `SomeContainer.createContents("hello");`

My condition is to put the class as an inner class in a generic class,then the code should be like this.

```
SomeContainer<T>.createContents(T);
```

That will produce compile time error. There is not any created references for `T`,also. Is there any way to create completly new `T` object inside the generic class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the type parameter `T` related to the type parameter of the enclosing generic class? It would be better if you show short version of your class.

Comment: Did you mean `SomeContainer<T>.createContents(T.class);`?

Comment: A better idea, instead of `Class<E>`, use `Class<? extends E>`; this way, someone can pass in an instance of a subclass's class, or use the `getClass()` method on an object (as it returns `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the reference type of the object) without a cast.

Comment: @ajb You can't use `.class` notation on a generic type parameter, because of type erasure.

Comment: @gparyani OK.  I really wasn't clear on whether T was supposed to be a generic parameter or just a dummy name he was using to ask his question.  I think some actual code would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry friends. I misunderstood my problem. The comment form @gparyani can solve for problem.

Comment: What exactly I want is `T.class`.But because of type erasure I have to create new instance of `T` to be passed into `createContents(T)` method.Then my real question should be "Is it a common practice to create another new `T` to get such object type of `T`?"

Comment: In real Java world,is it common to create a new sample object to be passed into a generic class so that we get an new instance of such object from that generic class?

Comment: I want to know why "type erasure" is not terminated in Java. Is there any reason?

Comment: @John Runtime generics are on track for Java 10. The current version is Java 7, and Java 8 is on track for release in ~6 months as of writing.

Answer (score 1):

Due to implementation of generics in Java you must pass the `Class<T>` object for the further use.

Here is the example:

```
public class Outer<E> {

    private static class Inner<E> {
        E createContents(Class<E> clazz) {
            try {
                return clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }  

    private Class<E> clazz;
    private Inner<E> inner;

    public Outer(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.inner = new Inner<>();
    }


    public void doSomething() {
        E object = inner.createContents(clazz);
        System.out.println(object);
    }

}
```

Also you can use `<? extends E>`, proposed by @gparyani [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388281/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java-within-the-generic-class#comment27005274_18388281)

Comment: Oh great! You are the one who really understands my problem. But it's confusing for me if  `Inner<E> inner =new Inner<>();` is valid and how it is different from `Inner<E> inner = new Inner<E>();`

Comment: @johnkarka Here is the diamond syntax introduced in Java 7, it's some kind of type inference, compiler will substitute type by itself.   For Java 6 you should use `Inner<E> inner = new Inner<E>();`.

Comment: @johnkarka BTW mutlicatch will work starting from Java 7 too.

Comment: `multicatch` ? please explain

Comment: @johnkarka In Java 6 you can catch only one type of exceptions, so you must write catch-block for every type, you want to catch:
`catch (IOException ex) { logger.log(ex); } catch (SQLException ex) { logger.log(ex); }` 

In Java 7 new syntax was introduced. The example above can be rewritten as:
`catch (IOException|SQLException ex) { logger.log(ex); }`