# Mathched type parameter at compile time to a specific type

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass<T>{
    public void method(){
        new T();//Compile error
    }
}
```

Does there exist a code example where type parameter can be matched to a specific type? 
This error causes because at the type checked at compile time compiler doesnt match type parameter `T` to a specific type. I know that we can apply reflection API to create instance of `T`.

Comment: Your client code knows about the actual type of `MyClass`. Why don't you create an instance of that type outside the constructor and pass it as an argument?

Comment: You can't create a new instance of a generic type. (Ever. Anywhere. Without using reflection, which I don't recommend).

Comment: Please read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java) and I hope you will understand better.