# Construct an object of generic type

Tags: java, generics

A method takes a class `cls` as parameter and I need to instantiate a cls object.
Something as follows:

```
private void foo(Class<?> cls){
  cls bar = new cls();
  ...
}
```

For example, let's say cls is Integer.class (but solution should work for any class).
How can I instantiate an Integer inside that method?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java

Comment: @aru that won't help because there's not a default constructor for `Integer`

Comment: Generics are not involved here.

Comment: By calling one of its constructors. Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the type and create a new integer:

```
if(cls == Integer.class) return Integer.valueOf(0);
```

or

```
if(cls == Integer.class) {
    return cls.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(0);
}
```

However this method would still return an object, not an instance of `Integer`.

A better option could be something like:

```
static <T extends Number> T newNumber1(Class<T> tClass, String s){
    if(tClass == Integer.class){
        return (T) Integer.valueOf(s);
    }
}

// OR

static Number newNumber2(Class<? extends Number> tClass, String s){
    if(tClass == Integer.class){
        return Integer.valueOf(s);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int v1 = newNumber1(Integer.class, "5");
int v2 = newNumber2(Integer.class, "6").intValue();
```

**UPDATE**:

```
static <T> T newInstance(Class<T> tClass, String s) throws Exception{
    return tClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Double d = newInstance(Double.class, "4");
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: I edited the OP, it should be more clear now.

Comment: @Niccolò My answer is for the method signature you added, except that your method is `void`. What does not work for you?

Comment: I would avoid the explicit use of 'Integer' in the method code. To me worked fine to change the signature from foo(Class<?> cls) to foo(Class<T> cls) and then T bar=cls.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(something). After all, that will work with basic types (String, Integer, Double ...)

Comment: So you need only the `String.class` constructor? I've added an example for this case. In case you need other constructors, you might want to check the type of the input class.

Comment: Yes, in my case the String constructor is all I need, after all it works for most of the class representing the basic types. Also my emphasis was more on the use of newInstance, getConstructor and on what to call them and how to return the correct type. Btw, you don't really need to cast the object to tClass as the object has been created by tClass constructor (do you?)

Comment: Yes, you are right - the cast is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Integer` class doesn't have a 0-arg constructor, you can't directly use [`Class#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method here.

Rather, you can get the appropriate constructor, taking `String` or `int` argument using [`Class#getConstructor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method. And then create instance using that:

```
Class<Integer> clazz = Integer.class;
Integer value = clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("5");
```

Comment: well, as I wrote the class is passed by as a parameter [ex. foo(Class<?> cls)], so I can't write the first line of your code. In your second line I need to substitute 'Integer' with the type given at runtime. But the compiler complains..

Comment: Do you just want to do this for `Integer`? If yes, then why not change the parameter to `Class<Integer>`. And why have that method in the first place. Please clarify your requirement.

Comment: I edited the question, it should be clearer now. As a matter of fact I already got to the solution starting from your current answer. Just instead of foo(Class<?> cls) I wrote foo(Class<T> cls) and then I can use your second line of code as 'T bar=cls.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(something)'. Would you like to improve your question to get accepted?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're asking about the general case - how do I create an instance of whichever class was passed into such a method.  Clearly, if you just mean "how do I create an `Integer`", then it's nothing to do with that method.

From the [Javadoc for Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)

```
public T newInstance()
          throws InstantiationException,
                 IllegalAccessException
```

> Creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object. The class is instantiated as if by a new expression with an empty argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.

Obviously, this won't work for `Integer`, as there is no constructor for `Integer` with an empty parameter list.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted.

Comment: `Integer` has no nullary constructor.

Comment: Yeah, my fault for clicking "Submit" when I was partway through typing it.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I don't mean to pick nits (especially since this is a poor Q in the first place) but the OP does say he wants to use `Integer`. It's unlikely the method is of any use period, of course, since with the wildcard you have no idea what the class is.

Comment: I took that to be an example.  Like if he had said "I want to write Hello World to the console", I would seriously doubt that he has an actual need to print the words "Hello World" - rather, he wants to know how to print any old text.  Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I took it to mean "I've got a `Class<?>`, now how do I instantiate it in the general case".  Which WOULD be a useful question, if he had asked it more clearly.

Comment: Exactly, and I indeed get a Class<?> that I should instantiate. Anyway if the question is not clear (it seemed to me) or it is otherwise ambiguous, there is always button "add comment" to ask clarification etc etc before either downvote or provide poor answers @BrianRoach

Comment: @Niccolò Please don't feel offended nor offend anyone. There is no personal comments here. Comments are merely added for questions and answers.

Comment: No offense intended :) I was just surprised by the speed of comments and votes (both to question and answers), without actually anyone asking clarification.

Answer (score -1):

If you use it in reflect method, I think you should use

```
Integer.TYPE
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but `Integer.TYPE` != `Integer.class`.