# How to create generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I've defined a class like this:

```
public class MyClass<T implements MyInterface> {
    public T getMy() {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

This won't compile. I'm not allowed to create the generic type T.

How can I solve this? Is there any good patterns to do this? Can I solve this by using an abstract class instead of the interface? Do I have to use reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing an actual class type (e.g. to the constructor), `Class<T>` and calling `newInstance()` on it if default constructor is OK with you.
If you need another constructor you would need to use reflection API, e.g. via `getDeclaredConstructors()` on this very class type object.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `implements` here.

```
<T implements MyInterface> // can't use interface.
```

So you can use Abstract Class there

```
<T extends MyAbstractClass>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyInterface> {

   T getMy(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here.

- Your syntax for creating a bounded generic type is incorrect; you need to use the `extends` keyword.  [The `extends` keyword is more general](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) in this sense, since it's used to mean that the generic type could either extend another class, or implement an interface.
- You can't instantiate a generic type directly.  Here's a clunkier way (without reflection, as it were), which was [provided by this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75254/1079354):

  ```
  public T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
      return clazz.newInstance();
  }
  ```