# java - Generic Return Type?

Tags: java, generics, syntax

I'm not certain if this is possible in Java. Also, I'm not able to figure out what to query on Google for this.
Anyway, I want a method that takes as an argument a Class (interface or class) and the method's return type is an instance of that Class. I don't want to have to recast an Object after the fact.

I'm not certain if this feature exists or what the syntax would be. Let's say I have a class named XYZ and here is my pseudo method.

```
private XYZ createInstance(XYZ.class, other args) {
  ...
  // create an instance of XYZ with other args named "_xyz_"
  ...
  return _xyz_;
}
```

Now assume XYZ is some sort of generic syntax. Is this possible at all in Java? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is this a duplicate of? The question linked below doesn't match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private <T> T createInstance(Class<? extends T> c) {
    return c.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: This is the same approach as the answer given in [Create instance of generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Use the diamond operator:

```
private <T> T createInstance(Class<T> concreteClass){
  return concreteClass.newInstance();
}

//usage
Integer i = instanceWithThatMethod.createInstance(Integer.class);
```

To pass "arguments", you have to get the Constructor of the class matching the desired parameter types, and invoke the call on that one, like this:

```
private <T> T createInstance(Class<T> concreteClass, String stringArg){
    return concreteClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(stringArg);
}

//usage
SomeClass s = createInstance(SomeClass, "testString");

//equals
SomeClass s = new SomeClass("testString");

//where SomeClass HAS to serve:
public SomeClass(String s){
  ...
}
```

Comment: How could we support multiple args?

Comment: @MingtaoZhang `getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)` is varargs - you could use `concreteClass.getConstructor(Integer.class, String.class, List.class)` and will then receive the reference to `public SomeClass(Integer i, String s, List l)`

Comment: I am wondering whether we could accept (Object... args) as second parameter for createInstance. Something like this  Class[] types = new Class[args.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
   types[i] = args[i].getClass();
  }
     return c.getConstructor(types).newInstance(args);

Comment: @MingtaoZhang You would need to convert each object to its classType to obtain the constructor. `getConstructor` takes `Class<?>...` - not (wrong syntax): `?...`

Comment: I think it should be part of the answer :)

Comment: @MingtaoZhang Problem: You need to provide the ClassTypes and the values at the same time: `createInstance(Class<T> concreteClass, Object... args, Object... values)` in order to do something like `return concrete.class.getConstructor(args).newInstance(values);` - meaning: `createInstance(SomeClass.class, Integer.class, String.class, 5, "Hello Word")` - but double varargs are not supported.

Comment: Do those args carry both value and type in runtime?

Comment: @MingtaoZhang no. If you pass "values" like (`1,"Hello World",false`) you need to use .getClass() to determine their class type, which you can't use to find a constructor. If you pass `Integer.class, String.class, Boolean.class` - there are no values associated.

Comment: true. Primitives are special in this context ...