# Java generic return type (with similar input parameters)

Tags: java, generics

This questions is close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349329/java-generic-return-type), but there is a major difference.

May requirements:

(1) I want to generate a Java function with generic return value.

(2) The list of input parameters is always the same. (unlike in [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349329/java-generic-return-type)).

(3) The function shall know, which type of return parameter is expected.

My tries:

```
public  <T> T getProperty(String name)
    { 
        T value;
        try {
            if (T instanceof String) {value = (T) getStringProperty(name);}
            if (T instanceof Long) {value = (T) getLongProperty(name);}
            if (T instanceof Boolean) {value = (T) getBooleanProperty(name);}           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error at getProperty", e);

        }
        return value;
    }
```

This it is not working, since no instance of `T` is generated. Trys with `T value = new T();` also failed.

Any quick fixes? Or is this approach not recommended?

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that you can't use `instanceof`, this is a bad approach, because you could write `String stringProp = TheClass.getProperty("foo"); Integer integerProp = TheClass.getProperty("foo");`: only one of these can succeed, but it fails at runtime. The same applies to @Chriss' answer:  `String stringProp = TheClass.getProperty(String.class, "foo"); Integer integerProp = TheClass.getProperty(Integer.class, "foo");` fails at runtime.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, and there's a valid answer to accomplish the OP's goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) of generics at runtime. In other words `<T>` will be erased to `Object` in your case.

You can pass a Class-Object like this to describe the return type:

```
public  <T> T getProperty(Class<T> returnType,String name){
   if (returnType == String.class)
       return (T)stringProperty(name);
   [...]
}
```

Comment: This works but be aware that it bypasses type safety in that `getProperty(String.class,"someName") will throw a runtime exception if the property `someName` is not of type `String`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm aware that some type checking has to be done by myself, when using this function.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886677/knowing-type-of-generic-in-java) and from [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) you will find that **You can not check the type of generic T**

So all you have to do is pass type parameter in your method or change your code design.

Pass type parameter:

```
public  <T> T getProperty(Class<T> returnType, String name){
    if (returnType == String.class)
        return (T)stringProperty(name);
    [...]
}
```

Or call the `getStringProperty()`, `getLongProperty()` etc methods directly instead of calling `getProperty()` generic method.

Comment: How to check the type of `T`. Still use `T instanceof String`?

Comment: since <T> is a type parameter and not an instance you can't use ´instanceof´

Comment: Sorry, you can not check the type of T.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way :
public static  Object getValue(Object str){

```
     if(str instanceof String){
          return   str;
     } if(str instanceof Integer){
          return   str;
     } if(str instanceof Long){
          return   str;
     } if(str instanceof Double){
          return   str;
     } if(str instanceof Float){
          return   str;
     } if(str instanceof BigDecimal){
          return  str;
     }

     return null;
}
```

or
public static   T getValue(Object str){

```
     if(str instanceof String){
          return  (T) str;
     } if(str instanceof Integer){
          return  (T) str;
     } if(str instanceof Long){
          return  (T) str;
     } if(str instanceof Double){
          return  (T) str;
     } if(str instanceof Float){
          return  (T) str;
     } if(str instanceof BigDecimal){
          return  (T) str;
     }

     return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I got already a suitable answer by Chris already (see checkmark left to his answer).