# Instantiate generic class using runtime class of an object

Tags: java, generics

I have this generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    public void myMethod(T arg) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I get an instance of this class which uses the class of an object as generic type `T`?

That is if I have:

```
SomeClass o = new SomeClass()
```

How can I get an instance of `MyClass<SomeClass>` by getting the runtime class of `o`?

Basically what I need is something like this (I know this doesn't make sense... it's just to give an idea):

```
MyClass<o.getClass()> m = new MyClass<o.getClass()>()
```

Is it possible? If not, can I achieve my goal of having an instance of `MyClass` which has a method that takes an argument of the same type of the runtime type of `o`? (yes, it has to be that exact type, cannot be a superclass...)

**Reflection is an option here!**

Thanks!

Comment: Generics don't exist at all at runtime.

Comment: @Adam Arold how are they the same question?

Comment: They're not. You don't want to determine the generic type of a given generic object, you want to create one using a given runtime-determined type. Interesting question.

Comment: This question has been answered like 313432 times. I have answered it at least 2-3 times. Do some research before you ask something here.

Comment: @Adam Arold I did, and didn't find it... I don't see the connection with the question u linked...

Comment: Looks like he had a point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java).

Comment: @Misha I still don't see a connection to my question, if you do, could you please give an answer to my specific case?

Comment: I think part of the issue is that you're posing an impossible question: "How can I get an instance of MyClass<SomeClass> by getting the runtime class of o?" Due to type erasure, generics don't exist at runtime (for the most part), so you can't create an instance of `MyClass<SomeClass>` at runtime; you can only create `MyClass` instances. An alternative could be to pass a `Class` instance for a type token, but whether that would work for you, I'm not sure. It's worth a try.

Comment: Can you show an example of where you would use this?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I need to use this in combination with Guava's EventBus... I need to dynamically create listeners for specific events classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of runtime type erasure, the runtime object created by `MyClass<X>` and `MyClass<Y>` will be identical. The fact that `new MyClass<X>().myMethod()` can be called on an `X` but not on a `Y` is a compile-time fact, not a run-time one. The compile-time question is "can it be called *on this variable*", not "can it be called *on objects with the same result of `getClass()`*".

You can create factory methods to create generic instances of your class based on the compile-time types of `Class` objects, or of the actual objects you wish to use it with:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    // ...

    public static <T> MyClass<T> forClass(Class<T> c) {
        return new MyClass<T>();
    }

    public static <T> MyClass<T> forObject(T object) {
        return new MyClass<T>();
    }
}
```

If you want your generic class's method to actually have *runtime* type checking, that's possible, too. Just store a `Class` object for the type in your `MyClass` instance, and use its `isInstance()` or `cast()` method to check the type of the argument to your method. You have to do this manually, because this is not what is usually done for ordinary generic classes, which is because it is usually unnecessary.