# In Java, why can't you use a constructor on generic classes?

Tags: java, generics

What's the logic behind the limitaion of doing the following in Java?

```
public class genericClass<T>{
    void foo(){
       T t = new T(); //Not allowed
    }
}
```

Comment: `T` is undefined at runtime, because there's only one copy of the byte code.  So the JVM can't tell which class to instantiate.

Comment: If you could, what would happen if `T` didn't have a no-args constructor, or it was private, or `T` was an interface? (What would `new genericClass<List>().foo()` do?)

Comment: Because `T` is not real -- it's just a fig newton of the compiler's imagination.  There is no constuctor to call -- the type of `T` is not even known at runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of type erasure.

The runtime does not know the "real" type of T, it is Object for it. You code would be more or less read like this:

```
public class genericClass {
    void foo(){
       Object t = new Object(); //Not allowed
    }
}
```

If you need to do such a thing, you need to use reflection:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
  private final Class<? extends T> clazz;
  public GenericClass(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }
  void foo() {
    T t = clazz.newInstance();
  }
}
```

Comment: But you can do new Object()

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer - But if you do `new Object()` you can't cast that to anything else.

Comment: Maybe it should be `T t = new Object()`

Comment: You will have `ClassCastException` when using t. Example: if you have a `T get()` method, and `GenericClass<Foobar> a`: `Foobar foobar = a.get()` will fail because the runtime type would be `Object`, and the expected type `Foobar` (on the left).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, generics is implemented using type erasure which means generic type information is erased at compile time. This means that the information for constructing the object isn't available at runtime.