# Spring MVC: WebArgumentResolver to resolve a list of arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

#### Situation

I am creating a `@RestController` with `spring-mvc` to handle URLs like the following:

`/api/products?attributes=brand:Audi,Mercedes&attributes=sector:Cars&...`

I want to extract the `@RequestParam List<AttributeValues> attributes` in the corresponding method.

The `AttributeValues.class` does have a `String name` and `Set<String> values` that is used later to retrieve the products that match this query.

#### Problem

I tried to use the `WebArgumentResolver` but this does apparently not work for Lists. I am now searching for any advice on:

- How to implement a custom resolver for lists (multiple values for the same param)?
- Is there a better solution for structuring the (REST) URL for such a use-case (again, multiple values for the same argument)? I could change the format.

#### Requirements

The `Product.class` has a `Set<Attribute> attributes` and I can therefore not use URLs like `/api/products?brand=Audi,Mercedes&sector=Cars` since these attributes could interfere with the properties on the `Product.class`.

Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@RequestParam`, you cannot bind to a `List<AttributeValues>` <strike>since the generic type information is lost upon compilation</strike>.

You can however bind to an array: `@RequestParam AttributeValues[] attributes`.

If you really want a `List`, another possibility is to use a custom annotation and to implement a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that checks if the parameter has that annotation, and which resolves the argument to a `List`.

```
@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
    return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(YourCustomAnnotation.class);
}

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(final MethodParameter parameter, final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                              final NativeWebRequest webRequest, final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    return ...; // a List
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I am stupid. Of course the generic type info is lost in Java after compilation. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hi @Tom, Hi fdomig, I cannot agree completely. Spring is somehow able to retrieve that type information. Otherwise features like \@Autowired List<MyInterface> wouldn't work right? And I for myself make heavy use of \@PathParam for lists of enums which is working fine as well. That's why I guess, that providing a custom WebDataBinder to the Controller could do the trick. Now I'm curious and will dig deeper ;)

Comment: Nah, boring ;) The reflection meta data stores all these information as well. This [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java) can give some background on how GenericType information is indeed accessible at runtime. Btw. I meant @RequestParam in my former comment of course. Cheers Ben.