# Java Reflection Generic Type ParamertizedType Object Creation Failing with java.lang.exception

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to generate the instance of typed class at run time to work with redis.

Here is my code, but its failing to create the instance of typed class T.

```
interface ObjectFactory<T>
{
    T create() throws Exception;
}
```

Here is the class that create the instance of T

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public class RedisObjectConstructor<T> implements ObjectFactory<T>
{

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T create() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            return (T) ((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is logic to actually set and get value of domain field:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RedisBasicEntity<T>
{
    private final ObjectFactory<T> factory;

    public RedisBasicEntity(ObjectFactory<T> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getFields(T redisDomain, Class<? extends Annotation> ann)
    {
        Map<String, String> redisHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Class<?> clazz = redisDomain.getClass();
        while (clazz != null)
        {
            for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields())
            {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ann))
                {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    try
                    {
                        Object value = field.get(redisDomain);
                        if (value != null)
                        {
                            redisHash.put(field.getName(), value.toString());
                            System.out.println(field.getName() + ":" + value.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {

                    }
                    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            c = c.getSuperclass();
        }
        return redisHash;

    }

    public T getRedisEntity(Map<String, String> redisHash, Class<? extends Annotation> ann) throws Exception
    {
        T redisDomain = factory.create();
        Class<?> clazz = redisDomain.getClass();
        while (clazz != null)
        {
            for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields())
            {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ann))
                {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    try
                    {
                        FieldUtils.writeDeclaredField(field, field.getName(), redisHash.get(field.getName()));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return redisDomain;
    }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.ranker.annotations.rediskey.RedisHashKey;
import com.ranker.api.dao.iListQualityDAO;
import com.ranker.app.redis.domain.list.ListQuality;
import com.ranker.app.redis.repository.support.RedisBasicEntity;
import com.ranker.app.redis.repository.support.RedisObjectConstructor;

public class ListQualityDAO implements iListQualityDAO
{
    @Autowired 
    private RedisBasicEntity<ListQuality> redisBasicEntity;

    public static ListQuality saveListQuality()
    {
        RedisObjectConstructor<ListQuality> redisObjectConstructor = new RedisObjectConstructor<ListQuality>();
        RedisBasicEntity<ListQuality> redisBasicEntity = new RedisBasicEntity<ListQuality>(redisObjectConstructor);
        ListQuality listQuality = new ListQuality();
        listQuality.setBurialScore(10.0);
        Map<String, String> redisHash = redisBasicEntity.getFields(listQuality, RedisHashKey.class);
        return null;
    }

    public static ListQuality getListQuality() throws Exception
    {
        RedisObjectConstructor<ListQuality> redisObjectConstructor = new RedisObjectConstructor<ListQuality>();
        RedisBasicEntity<ListQuality> redisBasicEntity = new RedisBasicEntity<ListQuality>(redisObjectConstructor);
        Map<String, String> redisHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        redisHash.put("satisfactionScore", "10.00");
        redisHash.put("burialScore", "5.00");
        redisHash.put("burialState", "true");
        ListQuality listQuality = redisBasicEntity.getRedisEntity(redisHash, RedisHashKey.class);
        return listQuality;

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ListQualityDAO.getListQuality();
    }
}
```

My Annotation that used to identify the field:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RedisHashKey {
}
```

Please let me know what am doing wrong here:

Here is the exception that am getting when i do test run:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception    at
>   com.ranker.app.redis.repository.support.RedisObjectConstructor.create(RedisObjectConstructor.java:19)
>     at
>   com.ranker.app.redis.repository.support.RedisBasicEntity.getRedisEntity(RedisBasicEntity.java:61)
>     at
>   com.ranker.api.dao.impl.ListQualityDAO.getListQuality(ListQualityDAO.java:37)
>     at
>   com.ranker.api.dao.impl.ListQualityDAO.main(ListQualityDAO.java:45)

Comment: Why are you throwing out the original exception in `RedisObjectConstructor.create()`? Wouldn't the original exception, with its type, description, and stack trace be more useful in diagnosing any problems?

Comment: This is just a test code,  Actually what i want to know here is how can I create the instance of T at run time: try
        {
            return (T) ((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           
        }

Comment: Right, well, you got rid of the exception that might have told you why, threw a new one, and are posting a stack trace for the new one. If you don't have a good reason to be doing that, I suggest you don't. Just don't catch the exception in `RedisObjectConstructor.create()`, and you'll see what your error is.

Comment: You should **almost never** catch an exception and then get rid of the exception you caught. But you're doing it almost every chance you get.

Comment: I got your point: here is the actual exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
 at com.ranker.app.redis.repository.support.RedisObjectConstructor.create(RedisObjectConstructor.java:14)
 at com.ranker.app.redis.repository.support.RedisBasicEntity.getRedisEntity(RedisBasicEntity.java:59)
 at com.ranker.api.dao.impl.ListQualityDAO.getListQuality(ListQualityDAO.java:37)
 at com.ranker.api.dao.impl.ListQualityDAO.main(ListQualityDAO.java:45)

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like you might have already read the answer to your question, but missed part of it. [Is this what you read?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/75345/3004881) That answers your question: you can only do that trick **if you create a subclass.** They give an example of using an anonymous subclass to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As specified in this [stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime), I modified the `create` method of your `RedisObjectConstructor<T>` this way:

```
public class RedisObjectConstructor<T> implements ObjectFactory<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;

    public RedisObjectConstructor(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public T create() throws Exception {
        return type.newInstance();
    }
}
```

And instanciate it like this:

```
RedisObjectConstructor<ListQuality> redisObjectConstructor = 
            new RedisObjectConstructor<ListQuality>(ListQuality.class);
```

And there is no more cast exception problem.

Comment: See here we are explicitly passing the type, but what i need is at runtime it has to create the object based on the type. My Declaration SomeClass<T>, and when  i pass SomeClass<ListQuality> It should return the ListQuality Object and If i do SomeClass<User> I need to get the User object. Is this clear?? Main point here is i dont like to pass the Type here, I have to identify at run time based on the Type passed from ParameterizedType

Comment: As explained in the SO response I cite, you cannot access the type: it is no more present at runtime. In the example you give, the type is known at compile time, so why not using it ? If you want to create dynamically your DAO objects, given their class, I would suggest to go for `Class.forName("xxx")` construction and save somewhere the class name of your object.