# Constructor of parameter in generic method ( java )

Tags: java, templates, generics, constructor

I want to make a general function which will fill a `HashMap<String,TYPE extends GameObject>` based on contend of a text file. It should work for any `TYPE` which implements methods `getName()` and `fromString()`. Currently, I found obstacle, that I cannot call constructor of `TYPE`.

The code:

```
public static <TYPE extends GameObject> void loadHashMap( Map<String,TYPE> mp, String filename ){
    BufferedReader reader = FileSystem.getReader( filename );
    String line;
    try{
        while( null != ( line = reader.readLine() )  ){
            TYPE item = new TYPE(); item.fromString( line ); // alternative 1
            // TYPE item = new TYPE( line );                 // alternative 2
            mp.put( item.getName(), item );
        };
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); };
}
```

where `GameObject` is defined as:

```
public class GameObject {
    String name;
    public String getName(){ return name; };
    public void fromString( String s ){ name = s;   }
    public GameObject ( ){  } 
    public GameObject ( String s ){ name=name; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java all template types are erased when compiling, so you are not supposed to do something like `new TYPE()`. You need to find another way to create an instance.

see [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java?lq=1)