# Java generics convert String to Int or Float depending on parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-conversion

I want to make generic function which fill up HashMap by either `Integer` or `Double` values depending on the type of parameter

basically I would like to put these two functions into one generic:

```
public static void MapFromString_Double( Map<String,Double> mp String s ){ 
    String [] words     = s.split("\\s+");
    for ( int i=0; i<words.length; i++ ){
        String [] tuple    = s.split("=");
        String name_string = tuple[0];
        String val_string  = tuple[1];
        Double num         = Double.parseDouble( val_string );
        mp.put( name_string, num ); 
    }
}

public static void MapFromString_Integer( Map<String,Integer> mp, String s ){ 
    String [] words     = s.split("\\s+");
    for ( int i=0; i<words.length; i++ ){
        String [] tuple    = s.split("=");
        String name_string = tuple[0];
        String val_string  = tuple[1];
        Integer num        = Integer.parseInt( val_string );
        mp.put( name_string, num ); 
    }
}
```

The input `String s` should be like `IronOre=10.0 Coal=30.0 LimeStone=20.0`

A non working code which ilustrates what I want si this:

```
public static <NUM extends Number> 
void MapFromString( Map<String,NUM> mp, String s ){ 
    String [] words     = s.split("\\s+");

    for ( int i=1; i<words.length; i++ ){
        String [] tuple = s.split("=");
        String name_string = tuple[0];
        String val_string  = tuple[1];


        // 1: is there any overriden string->Number conversion ?
        //NUM num = Number.decode( val_string );
        NUM num = Number.valueOf( val_string );

        // 2: alternative using some reflections ? Does not work either
        //NUM  num;
        //if( num instanceof Integer ){
        //  num = Integer.parseInt( val_string );
        //}else{
        //  num = Double.parseDouble( val_string );
        //}

        mp.put( name_string, num ); 
    }
}
```

I has probably a lot of connection to the problem that you cannot call constructor of parameter type in java, which is described here:
[Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java?lq=1)
But I'm hoping that in this simple case where parameter type is just a Number there will be some more clean way.

Comment: When you `split` a `String` you get a `String`, not a `Number` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with generics, for one because of type erasure, i.e. the fact that the type of `NUM` is unavailable at runtime.

However, in Java 8 it would be easy for the caller to provide the value parser:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Parser<T> {
    public T parse(String s);
}

public static <N extends Number> void MapFromString(Map<String, N> mp, String s, Parser<N> parser) {
    for (String word : s.split("\\s+")) {
        int idx = word.indexOf('=');
        mp.put(word.substring(0, idx), parser.parse(word.substring(idx + 1)));
    }
}
```

It would then be called like this:

```
Map<String, Double> doubleMap = new HashMap<>();
MapFromString(doubleMap, "...", Double::valueOf);

Map<String, Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>();
MapFromString(integerMap, "...", Integer::valueOf);
```