# How to instantiate a subclass without knowing It in advance?

Tags: java, object, generics, instantiation

I created the following class:

```
public class Abuser {
    <T extends Spam> List<T> createSpam() {
        List<T> lst =  new ArrayList<>();
        T s = new T();
        s.prepareAd();
        lst.add(s); 
        // the above is done unknown number of times
        return lst;
    }
}
```

to use with classes like this:

```
public class Spam {
    void prepareAd() {}
}
public class WildSpam extends Spam {}
public class MildSpam extends Spam {}
```

in the following way:

```
Abuser a = new Abuser();
Lost<WildSpam> wSpam = a.createSpam();
List<MildSpam> mSpam = a.createSpam();
```

How to make that work with a minimum fuss?

Comment: Well, you do know it in advance. So create two methods instead of just one: createWildSpam() and createMildSpam().

Comment: The utility of polymorphism in Java (or any OOP language) is precisely that you _want_ to use a `Spam` object without knowing what its particular implementation is.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Create instance of generic type in Java?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: @JB Nizet, class Abuser does not want to know about specific types of Spam

Comment: @Tim, consider Abuser a general purpose lib. The utility is to use WildSpam/MildSpam methods implicitly from within the lib without the lib even knowing about various types of Spam, but only about their parent class

Comment: @T.J., thanks, it looks similar.

Comment: @vkamenen then it should probably not be the one instantiating Spam objects. You can use `createSpam(Supplier<Spam> spamSupplier)` as method signature, and call it as `createSpam(WildSpam::new)`.

Comment: @JB, and what if createSpam have to create a lot of objects (as is in my case, although I simplified It)?

Comment: You'll then call it with `createSpam(SomeOtherSpam::new)`, or `createSpam(YetAnotherSpam::new)`, or whatever. What's the problem?

Comment: shouldn't it be Supplier<T>?

Comment: @JB, only createSpam knows how many objects has to be created

Comment: createSpam(), in your example, creates a single Spam object. So either your example is wrong, or your comment is wrong. You need to ask us the real question you would like us to answer.

Comment: @Turo yes, if the caller needs to know the type of the Spam being returned. If it just needs to know it's a Spam, then it can be Supplier<Spam>.

Comment: @Turo, I dont know what you mean

Comment: @JB, OK I editted it

Comment: So it creates several instances of the same type? Then call the supplier in a loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { list.add(supplier.get()); }`.

Comment: @vkamenen it was a question to JBs suggestion, and he answered it.

Comment: @JB,  your supplier needs to be told what objects to create. It is the same issue. Try to implement it.

Comment: Your code has `List<MildSpam> mSpam = a.createSpam();`. So the caller **knows** what type of Spam to create: `MildSpam`. So it can pass a MildSpam::new. If neither the caller nor the callee know what to create, how could something be created?

Comment: @JB, the issue is the lack of having types as first class objects in Java. In the concrette case the issue is how to tell a supplier that It shall be suppliying a certain kinds of objects

Comment: MildSpam::new creates instances of MildSpam. SomeOtherSpam::new creates instances of SomeOtherSpam. How does that not tell the supplier what kind of object to create?

Comment: @JB, as I said - try to implement it and you will see where the problem is

Comment: @vkamenen: no problem at all. http://ideone.com/MyUixt

Comment: @JB, You are right and I stay corrected. Thanks! I would have set this as an answer if I could

Comment: @JB, as far as I see this is a new feature introduced in Java 8. Unfortunatelly I have to use an older version

Answer (score -1):

Java should know what objects have to be created. You must pass some parameter to your method to inform it.

Like this:

```
public class Abuser {
<T extends Spam> T createSpam(T a) {
    T s = null;
    try {
        Class cls = Class.forName(a.getClass().getName());
        s = (T) cls.newInstance();
        s.prepareAd();
        // the above is done unknown number of times
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

Use it like this:

```
    Abuser a = new Abuser();
    WildSpam wSpam=new WildSpam();
    wSpam=a.createSpam(wSpam);
    MildSpam mSpam = new MildSpam();
    mSpam=a.createSpam(mSpam);
```

This code is for one object not a list of objects.

Comment: thanks. As in the related issue (from the comments) this seems the only feasible way with this crippled lang

Comment: That can only produce NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: You're right @JB. I'm sorry. I modified the answer. But it's for an object not a list of objects.