# Using generic type to create instance instead of reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection, factory-pattern

I have code that looks like follows:

```
public class Person{
    private Configuration configuration;
    public void act(){
        final Action action = new Factory().createAction(configuration);
        ....
    }
}

public class Factory{
    public Action createAction(Configuration configuration){
        Constructor<? extends Action> constructor =
                  configuration.getActionClass.
                  getConstructor(configuration.getClass());
        return constructor.newInstance(configuration);
    }
}

public class Configuration{
    private Class<? extends Action> actionClass;

    public void setActionClass(Class<? extend Action> cls){
        this.actionClass = cls;
    }

    public Class<? extends Action> getActionClass(){
        return this.actionClass;
    }
}
```

Each time `act()` is called, a new Action instance is created for some reason. I need to subclass `Action` and pass it to `act()`.

So I use reflection on a factory method to achieve that. But it seems overkill and not type safe.

Is it possible to repalce reflection with a type safe method such like generics?

Comment: If you add some type (ie. `Configuration<T extends Action>` and `Class<T> actionClass`) to your configuration, this can become type-safe

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generic+factory+%5Bjava%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to type erasure (see [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)) you can't avoid reflection and `Class<?>` arguments if you want to instantiate a type at runtime, so to answer your question it may be an overkill but `new T();` just isn't possible.

You could make it type safe however, by adding a generic type parameter to your `Configuration` class.

```
public class Configuration<T extends Action> {
    private Class<T> actionClass;

    public void setActionClass(Class<T> cls){
        this.actionClass = cls;
    }

    public Class<T> getActionClass(){
        return this.actionClass;
    }
}
```

And get rid of any *raw* references to it. (ie. switch `Configuration` to `Configuration<T>` wherever it's being used)

Comment: This also needs to be changed `public Action createAction(Configuration configuration)` to `public <T> T createAction(Configuration<T> config)`, so that it returns the parametric type and not just `Action`.

Comment: My intention is not to change the action at runtime, rather a fixed subclass of `Action`.

Comment: @bresai This solution is fine for that.

Comment: @biziclop sure, this is a good solution. But since no need to change action at runtime, why cannot I get rid of the reflection?

Comment: @bresai Because that's how type parameters have been implemented in Java. It was a known and planned shortcoming that offered what looked at the time like a good compromise between the new functionality and compatibility with pre-generics code.

Answer (score 0):

I got a very neat solution using new Function feature of Java 8 from a friend.

```
public class Person{
    private Configuration configuration;
    public void act(){
        final Action action = configuration.getActionFactory().apply(configuration);
        ....
    }
}

public class Configuration{
    private Function<Configuration, Action> actionFactory = Action::new;

    public void setActionFactory(Function<Configuration, Action> actionFactory){
        this.actionFactory = actionFactory;
    }

    public Function<Configuration, Action> actionFactory getActionFactory(){
        return this.actionFactory;
    }
}
```