# Instanciate generic Parameter of a class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a class

```
class Holder<SomeType extends AbstractType>{
    SomeType createType(){...}
}
```

then outside of it, I call

```
Holder holder = new Holder<MyType>();
```

I can't figure out how to implement the createType() method.

I tried about everything I could find in StackOverflow and the web, but I always run in the same dead end:
At runtime, if I do

```
TypeVariable typeVariable = getClass().getTypeParameters()[0];
System.err.println("typeVariable "+typeVariable);
```

I get "SomeType" instead of "MyType", and so I can't fetch the appropriate Constructor since I want to use Class.forName("MyType") and not Class.forName("SomeType") which lead to a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I use SomeType extends AbstractType, so I known all my MyTypes will have the same constructor available.

I can't use

```
ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) MyClass.class.getGenericSuperclass();
```

since Holder is not a Subclass of anything useful

I could do something like this in my Holder class, but I'm looking for a way to use reflection without having to pass an argument in the Constructor

```
private final Class<SomeType> type;

public Holder(Class<SomeType> type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

Trying all the various ideas I saw on the net feels like I'm chasing my tail, so I guess I'm missing an obvious element here.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : i can't solve it like in [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)
I can't pass the class as an argument of createType(Class) because I will not known the class at the moment of the call to createType (this method supposed to create the child of appropriate type when i can't known which type my children are supposed to be)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: Due to type erasure the generic type of the call `new Holder<MyType>()` isn't known at runtime so all you can do is pass that information somehow, e.g. by passing in the type class. Alternatively you could create subclasses e.g. `class MyTypeHolder extends Holder<MyType>` in which case you could [use reflection to extract the generic type](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860).

Comment: Perhaps you can change the declaration of createType to <T> T createType(Class<? extends AbstractType> clz) {} and then call it like SomeType sType = (SomeType)holder.createType(MyType.class); This way the class Holder doesn't have to be generic.

Comment: Are you referring to `.class.newInstance()` perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, i tried my approach to get rid of the 20+ MyType1Holder, MyType2Holder... I guess I'll just have to pass the class in the constructor of Holder to avoid type erasure. I you'd reply instead of comment, i could upvote your answer ;)

Comment: What is the signature of the constructor you want to use? And is `createType` the only method?

Comment: the signature the MyType(String someParameter) and no Holder has many methods. createType just creates a new child to be stores in a List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Thomas said in the comments, Java uses type erasure. That means that the concrete type that fills in `SomeType` is not implicitly passed to the `Holder`. But to instantiate a class, you need that type information. So you have to explicitly pass that information to `Holder`. There are several ways of doing this, one of which you have found. Which is passing a `Class` object to `Holder` when constructing it.

Java 8 introduces method references that also allow you to reference a constructor:

```
Function<String, MyType> cons = MyType::new;
```

This will create an instance of the functional interface `Function` that has a method `apply` that takes a `String` and returns a `MyType`.

You could then pass this functor to the constructor of `Holder`, and save it to use in `createType`:

```
class Holder<SomeType extends AbstractType>{
    private final Function<String, SomeType> cons;

    public Holder(Function<String, SomeType> cons) {
        this.cons = cons;
        ...
    }

    SomeType createType() {
        return cons.apply("SomeString");
    }
}
```

The advantage of this over using a `Class` in the same way, is that you know the signature of the constructor at compile time, and there are no exceptions thrown.