# Java Generics Call Constructor

Tags: java, list, generics, constructor

Let's assume I have four classes: `Car`, `Convertible`, `PickupTruck` and `CarManufacturer`.

`Car` is the abstract class that `Convertible` and `PickupTruck` inherit from:

```
public abstract class Car {
    private String name;
    private String colour;

    //Constructor
}
```

`Convertible` and `PickupTruck` both have parameterless constructors:

```
public class Convertible extends Car {
    private boolean roofUnfolded;

    public Convertible() {
        super("Convertible", "Red");
        this.roofUnfolded = false;
    }
}

public class PickupTruck extends Car {
    private double capacity;

    public PickupTruck() {
        super("Pickup Truck", "Black");
        this.capacity = 100;
    }
}
```

`CarManufacturer` stores a List of either `Convertibles` or `PickupTrucks`.

```
public class CarManufacturer <T extends Car>{
    private List<T> carsProduced = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

How can I implement a function `produceCar()` that calls the parameterless constructor and adds the object to the list? I tried:

```
public void produceCar(){
    this.carsProduced.add(new T());
}
```

Returning the error: `Type parameter 'T' cannot be instantiated directly`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same issues was solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315051/7380270

With regards to the problem, this works:

```
public class CarManufacturer <T extends Car> {
    private Supplier<T> carType;
    private List<T> carsProduced = new LinkedList<>();

    public CarManufacturer(Supplier<T> carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public void produceCar() {
        this.carsProduced.add(carType.get());
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarManufacturer<Convertible> convertibleCarManufacturer = new CarManufacturer<>(Convertible::new);
        convertibleCarManufacturer.produceCar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `Class<T>` to the `CarsManufacturer`, which will preserve the meta-information about the type-parameter at Runtime. This could allow you to instantiate `T`, by using the [`Class#newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) method:

```
public class CarManufacturer<T extends Car> {

    private List<T> carsProduced = new LinkedList<>();

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public CarManufacturer(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void produceCar() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        this.carsProduced.add(clazz.newInstance());
    }

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
CarManufacturer<Convertible> carManufacturer = new CarManufacturer<>(Convertible.class);
carManufacturer.produceCar();
```

Even though this should work, keep in mind that there are few notes that are worth mentioning:

- I wouldn't use the `Class<T>` member, just to get access to the type-parameter replacement at Runtime. I would rather add a `(T instance)` parameter to the `produceCar` method signature and directly add this instance to the list. Since you instantiate the `CarManufactured` by explicitly specifying the type-parameter, then there's no need to keep that `Class<T>`, because you already have the awareness of what the parameter is.
- I would rename the `produceCar` method to something more related to what the method does - for example, `saveCar()` or `addCar()`.

Comment: Well there are better ways than using reflections, but still a valid answer.