# Java: Instantiate a generic type by returning a Supplier vs returning a new instance

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I was reading how to instantiate a generic and after reading and applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315051/3399416); I would like to know what would be the differences between expecting a `Supplier<T>` vs. expecting a new instance of `T`.

Example:

```
abstract class AbstractService<T extends AbstractEntity> {
    protected Supplier<T> makeNewThing();  // supplier is expected

    public T myMethod(){
        T object = makeNewThing().get(); // local object by calling supplier
        object.doStuff();
        return object;
    }
}

class CarService extends AbstractService<Car> {
    public Supplier<Car> makeNewThing(){
        return Car::new;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
abstract class AbstractService<T extends SomeAbstractEntity> {
    protected T makeNewThing();  // object is expected, newness is assumed

    public T myMethod(){
        T object = makeNewThing(); // local object by calling constructor
        object.doStuff();
        return object;
    }
}

class CarService extends AbstractService<Car> {
    public Car makeNewThing(){
        return new Car();
    }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that expecting a supplier ensures that a new object will be created, but when expecting an object we can only assume that the implementing classes are calling the constructor and not re-using an existing instance.

I'd like to know of other **objective differences and possible use cases**, if any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently you missed the point. Unlike your `AbstractService` class, the `SomeContainer` of the linked answer is *not abstract*. It uses the supplier to return a new `T` every time needed. It does *not* hand out the supplier.

Comment: Thank you Holger. I want to know the differences in the example I provided.

Comment: In my opinion, the sample code presented in the question does not take advantage of using a `Supplier` over creating an instance using `new`..

Answer (score 12):

Using a `Supplier` postpones the creation of the instance.

This means that you might avoid a creation of an unnecessary instance.

For example, suppose you pass the output of `makeNewThing()` to some method.

```
public void makeNewThingSometimes (T newInstance)
{
    if (someCondition) {
        this.instance = newInstance;
    }
}

public void makeNewThingSometimes (Supplier<T> supplier)
{
    if (someCondition) {
        this.instance = supplier.get();
    }
}
```

Calling the first variant requires creating an instance of T even if you are not going to use it.

Calling the second variant only creates an instance of T when necessary.

Using a `Consumer` can save both storage (if the create instance requires a significant amount of memory) and time (if the execution of the constructor is expansive).

Answer (score 5):

> The only thing I can think of is that expecting a supplier ensures
>   that a new object will be created,

Not necessarily.
You implement the `Supplier` in this way :

```
 return SomeEntityImplementation::new;
```

But you could have implemented it in this other way :

```
 if (myCachedObject != null){
    return (()-> myCachedObject);
 }
 return SomeEntityImplementation::new;
```

Both ways may be used to return a cached object or create a new one.

---

One of `Supplier` advantages is the case of `Supplier` creating an object : this one is actually created only as the `Supplier.get()` method is invoked.

Note that in your example, using `Supplier` doesn't bring any advantage as in both cases (with or without `Supplier`) the object creation is already performed in a lazy way : as the factory method is invoked. 
To take advantage of it, you should have a method that provides a `Supplier<T>`  as parameter as in the Eran and Dasblinkenlight examples.

---

Another `Supplier` advantage is its ability to implement factory that may return multiple of things.
Using `Supplier` allows to have a shorter and more readable code and besides that doesn't rely on Java Reflection.

Supposing that you want to create the object from an `Enum` value, you could so write :

```
public enum MyBaseClassFactory {

  ENUM_A (A::new),
  ENUM_B (B::new),
  ENUM_C (C::new),
  ENUM_D (D::new);

  private Supplier<BaseClass> supplier;

  MyBaseClassFactory (Supplier<BaseClass> supplier){
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  public BaseClass createObject(){
       return supplier.get();
  }
}
```

You could so use it :

```
BaseClass base = MyBaseClassFactory.ENUM_A.createObject();
```

Without `Supplier`, you will have to use Reflection (that may fail at runtime) or write a verbose and unmaintainable code.

For example with Reflection :

```
public enum MyEnumFactoryClass {

    ENUM_A(A.class), ENUM_B(B.class), ENUM_C(C.class), ENUM_D(D.class);

    private Class<BaseClass> clazz;

    MyEnumFactoryClass(Class<BaseClass> clazz) {
       this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public BaseClass createObject() {
       return clazz.newInstance();
    }

}
```

For example without reflection but with more verbose code :

```
public enum MyEnumFactoryClass {

  ENUM_A {
     @Override
     public BaseClass createObject() {
        return new A();
     }
    },
    ENUM_B {
     @Override
     public BaseClass createObject() {
        return new B();
     }
    },
    ENUM_C {
    @Override
     public BaseClass createObject() {
        return new C();
     }
    },
    ENUM_D {
    @Override
     public BaseClass createObject() {
        return new D();
     }
    };
    public abstract BaseClass createObject();

}
```

You could of course take advantage in a close way of `Supplier` by using it with a `Map<String, Supplier<BaseClass>>`.

Answer (score 3):

The first solution is more flexible, because an extra level of indirection in object creation lets users of your class library change the source of new items independently of `ServiceImpl<SomeEntityImplementation>` class.

You can make a new `Supplier<T>` instance without subclassing or recompiling `ServiceImpl`, because there is an extra level of indirection. `ServiceImpl` could be implemented as follows:

```
class ServiceImpl<SomeEntityImplementation> {
    private final Supplier<SomeEntityImplementation> supplier;
    public Supplier<T> makeNewThing(){
        return supplier;
    }
    public ServiceImpl(Supplier<SomeEntityImplementation> s) {
        supplier = s;
    }
}
```

This makes it possible for users of `ServiceImpl` to provide their own `Supplier<T>`, which is not possible using the second approach, in which the source of new items is merged into the implementation of service itself.

Comment: +1.. One question though : Wouldn't dependency injection (i.e injecting a `SomeEntityImplementation` into `ServiceImpl`) be a better option for achieving inversion of control in this case? With the above approach mentioned in your answer, wouldn't client code that passes in a supplier be tightly coupled to an implementation? (Since the client code would pass in a lambda or method reference to the `ServiceImpl` constructor that cannot be swapped out from the client code)

Comment: @CKing Client code could certainly pass a lambda or a method reference, but it could also pass an instance of a class that implements `Supplier<T>`. If the client builds such a class, dependency could be injected into `ServiceImpl`, for example by using an inversion-of-control container.

Comment: So the class that implements the `Supplier` interface would act as a factory with its `get` method deciding what instance to return. Something on the lines of `public SomeAbstractEntity get() { if(userInput ==1 { return new SomeEntityImplementation() } else { return new SomeEntityImplementation2() } }`. The advantage this approach would have over a regular OOP factory would be that it delays the creation of the instance? Did I get that right?

Comment: @CKing Yes, supplier becomes a delayed factory in this scenario.