# Why does wrapping type parameter in the factory pattern work around type erasure?

Tags: java, generics

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/75254/156458

You can't do "new E".  But you can change it to

```
 private static class SomeContainer<E>
 {
     E createContents(Class<E> clazz)
     {
         return clazz.newInstance();
     }
 }
```

It's a pain.  But it works.  Wrapping it in the factory pattern makes
 it a little more tolerable.

I was wondering why the method works?

Why doesn't type erasure apply to `Class<E> clazz`, so it becomes `Class<Object> clazz`, and then `clazz.newInstance()` returns an instance of `Object`?

Thanks.

Comment: It does apply to it in the same way, the difference is that the actual `clazz` object at runtime still knows of what type it is, therefore enabling it to create an instance. You have an actual *instance* of something instead of just having a type `E`.

Comment: Because type erasure does not mean that `clazz` becomes `Class<Object>`. It means that it becomes `Class`, and the `newInstance` method will return an appropriate instance because of how polymorphism works in the first place. That's the whole point of having the `Class` reference in the first place. Not sure what is tripping you up here.

Comment: Reading through the source code implies:  "deep magic".  This isn't an attempt at being snarky.  The code literally calls a class which has the ability to delegate to *native* instantiators.  It can also invoke `Unsafe` in one branch.  Additionally, this method (eventually) performs the cast to `E` that makes it all work, but it's tough to infer just from reading the code alone.

Comment: Note that a `Supplier<E>` is a better way to pass around something to make instances, since it handles generics type-correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure does apply to `Class<E>`, but it becomes simply `Class` at runtime.  But it is still the `Class` object for a specific class that gets passed into the method at runtime.

The [`newInstance()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) returns its type argument, here an `E`, so the compiler knows that it will return the correct type.  But the `newInstance` method returns an `Object` in the JVM at runtime.

In the calling code, the compiler inserts a cast to the correct type, which is based on what `E` is in the calling code.  E.g. the code:

```
Foo f = new EnclosingClass.SomeContainer<Foo>().createContents(Foo.class);
```

"looks like" this in the JVM:

```
Foo f = (Foo) new EnclosingClass.SomeContainer().createContents(Foo.class);
```

The Factory Pattern here is simply using the `Class` object to provide the type for runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure does not mean that `clazz` becomes `Class<Object>`. It means that it becomes a plain, unadorned `Class` instance. The `newInstance` method will always invoke the constructor of the type that the class object represents because that is its entire purpose. Functionally, the type that the `Class` object represents is not encoded in the generics at all. You can intuit this by remembering that `Class` objects and `newInstance` worked just fine before Java 1.5 introduced generics in the first place.