# Inserting Object of type T into a Generic List

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Note: This is part of a test I had. The goal is to implement a ListArray on my own, said listarray should be able to store arbitrary types of objects. I am not allowed to use any other library classes such as LinkedList or ListArray that already exists and I am not allowed to ditch the array and implement a Collection. I *have to* implement a generic array of sorts.

The code below compiles, so I assume that the constructor works. The problem is that when the test asserts whether listArray[0] equals list.append(1) I get a nullPointerException. I think that the problem is that I need to create a new Object and insert that into the array, the problem is that I don't know what Object T will be, and therefore don't understand how I can create a new T with argument "element".

```
public class List<T> implements Seq<T> {

public T[] listArray;
public int size;
public int freeIndex;

public List(){
    this.listArray = (T[])new Object[10];
    this.size = 10;
    this.freeIndex = 0;
}

//have to create a new object
public void append(T element){
    this.listArray[0] = element; //need some sort of new T() method.
}
}
```

**UPDATE** I realize that append lacks functionality, that is the intention, I am solely focued on inserting an arbitrary Object T into the array.

**UPDATE1** I was overly focused with generics and missed that my constructor was wrongly written. I apologize if it seemed lazy, I have been trying to solve this for several hours but alas, I'm quite inexperienced in Java. I nonetheless got an answer to the problem of insterting an element to the generic Array. Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Which method calls the constructor? I can't find it. Can you please post a reproducible example of code?

Comment: List() is not a constructor. It's a method. Becouse you added `void` as the return type. Voting to close as typo. Next time, do a tiny bit of debugging. Add Sysout statements, or just execute your code with your debugger. Such mistakes are really easy to find.

Comment: You are not incrementing your array index when you insert

Comment: `public void List()` is not a constructor, try `public List()`

Comment: I'm sorry I did the constructor wrong, I was too focused on understanding generics that I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

If you try debugging you would see that  this.listArray is null.
Probably your intention for `public void List()` was to be constructor but it is not constructor. It is ordinary method. be `public List()` (no return type).

You definitely do not need `new T() method` to solve this problem (it is possible, see [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)).

Finally you will soon find that your append method works as nothing else 'put in first position'. In order to have complete append implementation you need

- update freeIndex
- resize array if it is too small to fit new element

You do not really need size as member variable, you could rely of listArray.length.

Answer (score -1):

You need to increment your array index when you insert

```
public class List<T> implements Seq<T> {

    private int incrementSize = 10;
    private T[] listArray = new T[incrementSize];
    private int size = 10;
    private int freeIndex = 0;

    public List(){
    }

    //have to create a new object
    public void append(T element){
        this.listArray[freeIndex] = element; //need some sort of new T() method.
        freeIndex++;
        if (freeIndex >= size) {
            increaseArraySize();
        }
    }

    private void increaseArraySize() {
        // create a new array with incrementSize extra buckets
        // copy old array into new array
        // point old array at new array
        // increment size
    }
}
```

Comment: Your member variables should be made protected or private, not public. If they are made public, someone can change them from outside your object and cause problems.