# Java 11 generics code generating unchecked warning

Tags: java, generics

In the example below, I can't seem to get rid of the unchecked warning (short of suppressing it). As you can see in '2.' specifying the type causes a compile error.

*Is suppression the only option here?*

```
static class Cat { }

static class CatGiver<T extends Cat> {

    T cat;

    CatGiver(T cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    static <T extends Cat> CatGiver<T> get() {
        // 1. Unchecked assignment warning
        return new CatGiver(new Cat());

        // 2. Compile error on 'new Cat()' "T cannot be applied to Cat..."
        // return new CatGiver<T>(new Cat());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to create an instance of `T` inside the method? If so, then the answer is "you can't, without additional work (such as passing a `Class<T>` in from the outside). See the answer I linked above.

Comment: Think about when you create an ArrayList, you say `List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();` so your first warning, you need to say `new CatGiver<Cat>( new Cat());` and specify the type.

Comment: @matt that causes a compile error "Incompatible types, Required CatGiver<T> but found CatGiver<Cat>"

Comment: Right, because you method has a Generic parameter, that  cannot be used. I have added an answer, if you actually need your class to have a `static <T extends Cat>` then you should have your `get` take an argument.

Comment: `return new CatGiver<>(new Cat())` and remove the generic type parameter from `get`

Comment: @Michael: that doesn't actually solve anything because `Cat` is not guaranteed to be assignable to `T`.

Comment: @Michael Have you tried to compile code with solution from your comment?

Comment: What is the purpose of having generic type `<T extends Cat>` in `static <T extends Cat> CatGiver<T> get() {` if you always `return new CatGiver(new Cat());`? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I think you are right. I was trying to achieve the ability to create other types later on that extend Cat. However, as that is not there yet, this example doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 2):

First you're creating a raw type. You need to specify the type. Second, your static method, the 'T' is not variable and you can only return a Cat.

```
static CatGiver<Cat> get() {

    return new CatGiver<Cat>(new Cat());

}
```

You could have your cat be a generic type by passing an instance of a cat or the Class as the answers in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java).

```
static <T extends Cat> CatGiver<T> get(T cat){
    return new CatGiver<>(cat);
}
```

Then the T *should* be acquired implicitly from the argument. (I haven't tested.)