# What type can be returned instead of null?

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> object) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readerFor(object).readValue(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What can I do to not return null?

Comment: You can return an `Optional`. If the conversion is successful, then it will contain a value, otherwise empty.

Comment: I just want to understand is it good approach to return null in general and what to do in a such case.

Comment: You don't want to `return null` in Java, because it will throw a NPE when someone tries to assign the return value of your method to a var. Looking at Optional may be your best bet if you want to handle the exception inside the method.

Alternatively you can catch the `JsonProcessingException ` and throw a NPE yourself if this value MUST NEVER be null.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz and one more question. Is it good idea to make such method in Utillty class and use it from anywhere or better to create separate class for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caller will have to deal with this being null/missing anyway so may as well specify that your method throws a JsonProcessingException and do exception handling in the caller. Then the caller can do whatever it needs for the type it needs.

Otherwise you're just handling the same issue twice.

```java
public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> object) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readerFor(object).readValue(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that:

> ObjectReader readerFor(`Class<?>` type) - Factory method for
>   constructing ObjectReader that will read or update instances of
>   specified type
>
> `<T> T` readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef) - Method
>   to deserialize JSON content from given JSON content String.

So the method is returning an instance of the generic type `Class<T>`, so you can [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java):

```
 public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> object) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T instance=null;
    try {
        instance = mapper.readerFor(object).readValue(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().
                getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).newInstance();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Now you will get a new instance if the result is null.