# Create instance of generic class member: Class<T>.newInstance() throws exception

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I want to make a generic class which stores a pool of temporary objects (such as 2D vector Vec2d ) so that I don't have to dynamically allocate them during my simulations. Based on these answers [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java/25195050#25195050) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) I come to this solution:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

class TempPool<T>{
  T[] objs;

  public TempPool(Class<T> c, int n) {
    T[] a = (T[])Array.newInstance(c, n);                // initialize the array
    try{ // Compiler forces me to use try fo handling                     
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++) a[i]=(T)c.newInstance();   // initialize fields in the array
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e +" in TempPool()" );
    }
    objs = a;
  }

  T    borrow(  ){ return objs[icur++];    };
  void repay(T o){ 
    if( o != objs[icur] ) objs[-1]=null; // Throws exeption
    }else{ icur--; }
  }
```

But when I try to use

```
class Vec2d{ double x,y; }

tmpVec2d   = new TempPool       (Vec2d.class,10);   // tried both
//tmpVec2d = new TempPool<Vec2d>(Vec2d.class,10);   // tried both
```

it it throws exception
`Exception thrown  :java.lang.InstantiationException: Boulders_rigid$Vec2d in TempPool()`

Comment: Can you use `Supplier<T>` instead of passing a `Class<T>`?

Comment: "// Throws exeption" why not just throw an exception explicitly?

Comment: Please don't shallow the exception. At least, print the stack trace.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn more than don't shallow print it, don't catch it at all. The instance will be in a part-initialized state of an exception is thrown, so you'd get problems like NPEs from trying to use the "pooled" objects it hands out. Best just to propagate the exception.

Comment: I said "At least". It's the absolute bare minimum you should do. Now this question is missing debugging details (the stack trace), so I voted to close it as that.

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes do not work how you think they work.

An inner class looks like this:

```
class Outer /* must be a class; not an interface */ {
    class Inner /* A class (not an interface), AND, not static {
    }
}
```

Inner class have a secret, invisible final field that looks like:

```
private final Outer magicThis;
```

that cannot be `null`. Every constructor that `Inner` has, has as first parameter `Outer magicThis`, but this parameter is also hidden. To pass it, you use this weird syntax:

```
outerInstance.new Inner();
```

and, crucially, which makes it 'magic', in the sense that you didn't know it worked this way, if `Outer.this` was a legal expression (which it is, in any non-static method inside `Outer`, for exmaple), `Outer.this` is silently assumed as outerInstance: In those contexts, and only in those, just `new Inner()` works.

Now that you know all this, you then understand that invoking `newInstance()` on a non-static inner class does not work: That requires a no-args constructor and there isn't one: All constructors have that secret, invisible `Outer magicThis` parameter.

You can observe all this by using the `javap` tool.

The solution is simple: Mark your inner class as `static`. In fact, go ahead and mark *all* your inner classes as static. Only make non-static inner class if you really know what you are doing and you are absolutely sure you really want that - the magic stuff tends to throw people off and make it easy to make wrong assumptions about code. For example, that secret ref to the outer? That can really trip you up with garbage collection (it prevents the outer instance from being collected!).

Note that your code has very crappy quality. A few things to look into:

1. The correct "I have no idea what to do" exception handler is NEVER to just log it and forget it, and System.out is not an appropriate logging locatino. Just `e` throws away almost all relevant information - in particular the cause which is what you do NOT want to throw away. The right I dunno handler for an exception block is *always* this: `throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);`. This is short, simple, does not cause code to continue to run in an unknown state, and preserves all information. Fix this.
2. Don't call `newInstance()` on a class; it is deprecated. It has crazy exception behaviour. You want `c.getConstructor().newInstance()` instead.
3. `objs[-1] = null` of course throws ; there is no -1 index. Presumably you want `objs[icur] = null`? Or perhaps `objs[objs.length - 1] = null;`? I'm not sure what `repay` is trying to accomplish.

Comment: "You want `c.getConstructor().newInstance()` instead." *if you must use reflection*. This relies on there being a no-arg constructor, which you can't check at compile time. It would be better to provide a `Supplier<T>` (or `Supplier<? extends T>`, generally), which provides better compile-time safety.

Comment: Certainly. I think we have slightly different opinions on exactly how much refactoring is warranted in an answer to this question, but, having a Supplier is certainly a nicer design than sticking with newInstance().

Comment: It's also worth noting that if they do want to instantiate a non-static inner class using reflection, they have to use `c.getConstructor(OuterClass.class).newInstance(outerInstance)`, as if they were really calling a constructor with the magic outer instance parameter. This is documented in the documentation for `Class.getConstructor()` and `Constructor.newIntance()`.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to use reflection in this way.

Look at the source code of `java.util.ArrayList`: it doesn't declare an array of type `E[]` to hold the elements: it uses an `Object[]`, and applies casts.

So, you can do this instead:

```
class TempPool<T>{
  Object[] objs;

  public TempPool(Class<T> c, int n) {
    objs = new Object[n];  // Simple!
    // ...
  }

  // Unchecked cast, but it's safe to suppress because you're ensuring only
  // instances of T are in here if you use it correct.
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked");
  T    borrow(  ){ return (T) objs[icur++];    };
  
  // No changes needed to repay.
}
```

Also, instead of relying on reflection through `Class<T>`, pass a `Supplier<T>` (or, better, a `Supplier<? extends T>`): reflective instantiation is very error-prone, because you need to ensure that you're passing a `Class` with a zero-arg constructor that throws no checked exceptions etc ([rzwitserloot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66063989/3788176) describes another of the problems specific to inner classes). A `Supplier<T>` is checked at compile time to ensure such a constructor exists; and it doesn't throw checked exceptions, so it substantially declutters the code.

```
  public TempPool(Supplier<? extends T> c, int n) {
    objs = new Object[n];  // Simple!
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) objs[i]=c.get();
  }
```

Or, if you want to be streamy:

```
objs = IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> c.get()).toArray();
```

You can now invoke like this:

```
tmpVec2d   = new TempPool<>(Vec2d::new,10);
```

---

Of course, a neater solution with no explicit casting would be simply to use a `List<T>`:

```
class TempPool<T>{
  List<T> objs;

  public TempPool(Class<T> c, int n) {
    objs = IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> c.get()).collect(toList());
    // ...
  }

  // No cast required in borrow:
  T    borrow(  ){ return objs.get(icur++);    };
```