# Java generic method: create entity of necessary type

Tags: java, generics

There are two entities classes:

```java
public class Base {
    private String provider;
}

public class SuperClass extends Base {
    private String trunk;
}
```

and main class:

```java
public class Test {
    public static <T extends Base> List<T> getDetailedReport(Class<T> clazz, String providerName) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        T entity = new Base(); // this is wrong, of course.
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Base();
        ​SuperClass superClass = new SuperClass();
        List<Base> baseList = getDetailedReport(Base.class, "Telia");
        List<SuperClass> superClassList = getDetailedReport(SuperClass.class, "Globalcom");
    ​}
​}
```

I'm trying to create generic method `getDetailedReport` which returns list of entities. Type of entity is passed through `clazz` variable.
My question is: How to create entity of necessary type?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java

Comment: You could use reflection, i.e. the `newInstance()` method on `Class` or one of the constructors. However, you seem to need parameters (like provider for both and trunk for `SuperClass`) so some kind of factory might be better suited here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529555/how-do-i-pass-in-a-type-as-an-argument-in-java/67529730#67529730

Answer (score 0):

Reflection API is your friend here. To use the following implementation, you need to make sure the following conditions:

1. The `Base` and all the derived objects have no-args constructor (i.e. `new Base()` or `new SuperClass()`).
2. You need deal with 4 thrown exceptions: `NoSuchMethodException`, `IllegalAccessException`, `InvocationTargetException`, `InstantiationException`.

Minimal sample (using Lombok):

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class Base {
    private String provider;
}
```

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class SuperClass extends Base {
    private String trunk;
}
```

```
@SneakyThrows
static <T extends Base> List<T> getDetailedReport(Class<T> clazz, String provider) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    T entity = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    entity.setProvider(provider);
    list.add(entity);
    return list;
}
```

```
List<Base> baseList = getDetailedReport(Base.class, "Telia");
List<SuperClass> superClassList = getDetailedReport(SuperClass.class, "Globalcom");

System.out.println(baseList);
// [Main.Base(provider=Telia)]

System.out.println(superClassList); 
// [Main.SuperClass(super=Main.Base(provider=Globalcom), trunk=null)]
```

- I made the data classes `static` in order to use in the class with the main method comfortably
- I used `@SneakyThrows` for safe of answer clarity - you, however, need to handle these exceptions
- Note that `@NoArgsConstructor` satisfies `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`.
- You might need to modify the implementation as you need (I let the method pass `String provider` into a newly created instance through the Reflection API and returned it in the `List` as a demonstration).