# Creating List in runtime using Java reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to solve the problem of creating a List in runtime.
I created method

```
private <GT, LT> LT getList(Class<GT> genericType, Class<LT> listLype) throws Exception {
    Constructor<LT> c = listLype.getConstructor();
    ...
    ???
}
```

where LT - type of List I want to create (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc), and GT - generic type of List.
How can I create`LT<GT>` List?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` do not care about the element type. Use `return c.newInstance();` and you’re done; that’s compatible with your return type `LT`. You might notice that `GT` has no effect here at all.